# PVS output not showing drive

Tags: linux, lvm, storage, cluster, san

I had created physical volume earlier i.e. /backup, /ndasdb, /processor, /latro.

Don't know what exactly happened, but /ndasdb is not showing in any of this output result:

Pvdisplay, Vgdisplay, and lvdisplay. rest   3 are showing.

I can see the lun in multipath -ll  (ndasdb is there)

I tried to recreate it with `pvcreate /dev/mapper/ndasdb` but its gives me this error:

```
WARNING: gfs2 signature detected on /dev/mapper/ndasdb at offset 65536. Wipe it? [y/n]: n
  Aborted wiping of gfs2.
  1 existing signature left on the device.
```

Is it true if I do yes it will delete my all data?
Is there anyway to bring my drive back without loosing any data?

[image: lsb output]

Comment: To understand how your disks have been set up, can you provide the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: kindly download the output result from this below linke https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wobgracp5gd5ie8/AACKoct3h3U3d31lTDtibXMca?dl=0

Comment: Instead of using an external link, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/491819/edit) your question to include the output from lsblk.

Comment: i did it kindly check

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true if do yes will delete my all data?

Yes, you are right because you will write LVM data inside the disk.

> is there anyway to bring my drive back without loosing any data.

As `pvcreate` command detected a GFS2 filesystem intact in the disk and assuming it can be mounted, you can proceed as follows:

1. Create a mount point and a backup folder:
   `mkdir /mnt/{mountpoint,backup}`
2. Mount the disk:
   `mount -t gfs2 /dev/mapper/mdasdb /mnt/mountpoint`
3. Copy the data in `/mnt/mountpoint` folder to `/mnt/backup`:
   `cp -r /mnt/mountpoint/ /mnt/backup/`
4. Now your data should be in `/mnt/backup` folder.

Comment: Hello thanks for reply, i could not understand well. please how will i mount it? what info are you asking to extract ? please i would be really greatful to you if could tell me the step by step process.  thanks in advance.

Comment: if i am getting you right i trid to mount with this, mount /dev/mapper/ndasdb /ndasdb. it says "mount: mount(2) failed: No such file or directory
"   please let  me know how can i mount and take my info to a backup location.

Comment: @HimanshuDua I have modified the answer. Waiting for your feedback.

Comment: i tried do use this command.mount -t gfs2 /dev/mapper/ndasdb /mnt/
mount: mount(2) failed: No such file or directory.  it giving me this error

Comment: It looks like `/mnt` folder doesn't exit. Did you run the Step1 successfully? Please provide the output of `ls /mnt`.

Comment: yes /mnt is there

Comment: That's weird. Both the device `/dev/mapper/ndasdb` and the mount point `/mnt` exist but it keeps saying `mount(2) failed: No such file or directory`. Did you use any type of encryption when this worked? Also, could you please provide more info of your setup to see if we find something useful to try to replicate this issue?